# Can't get image to vertical align bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the image at the bottom of the page. The div is 100% height but vertical-align: bottom doesn't seem to work.

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpooxdva/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="bg">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="pic">
    <div class="leftlayer-gradient hidden-md hidden-lg text-center">
      <img src="https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3/3907.png" class="down-image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pic {
  background-image:url("left.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
}

.leftlayer-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.down-image {
  height: 8vh;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using vertical-align correctly.

Set the image a position absolute and the bottom value to 0:

```
.down-image {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
#pic {
  background-image: url("left.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
}
.leftlayer-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.down-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8vh;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="bg">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="pic">
      <div class="leftlayer-gradient hidden-md hidden-lg text-center">
        <img src="https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3/3907.png" class="down-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to the image:

```
.down-image {
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Output: http://jsbin.com/govujikumi/1/edit?html,css,output**

Comment: That worked thanks. I've noticed the image is actually slightly off-center. Do i need to offset its width by half?

Comment: @EdShee You need to use [centering](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)...